# Quotes with mixed style

Tags: csquotes

I'm using with lualatex 1.12 the package `csquotes` for proper quotation in German. The package parses if matching quotes are found and if not it complains. My question is: Is there a possibility to scan the text even if the quote is **NOT** set in the same *group*?

e.g. Beginning quote without bold but ending within, i.e. "**Wrong" text**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
    \enquote{Bold text 1}
    "{\bfseries{}Bold text2}"
    "{\bfseries{}Wrong" text3}
\end{document}
```

The desired solution would be to have the quotation marks set properly despite the the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially no. `csquotes` works with grouping and that grouping is deeply engrained into all of `csquotes`' code. (Grouping makes it possible to implement nested quotations without a lot of additional unnecessary bookkeeping.)

Here is an attempt to completely remove any grouping from the quotation commands used by `\MakeOuterQuote`. Nesting will not work as expected and I probably overlooked a ton of things, so expect breakages.

*Caveat emptor* This is more of an academic exercise to see if this could work, rather than code I would use in my real-world documents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\makeatletter
\protected\def\csq@oqmark@nogroup{%
  \global\advance\csq@qlevel\@ne
  \global\let\csq@oqmark\csq@qclose
  \global\let\csq@qclose@ii\csq@qclose@ii@nogroup
  \expandafter\csq@qopen
}

\let\csq@oqmark\csq@oqmark@nogroup

\let\csq@qclose@ii@orig\csq@qclose@ii

\def\csq@qclose@ii@nogroup#1{%
  \ifdim\lastkern=\csq@omitmarker
    \global\advance\csq@qlevel\m@ne
    \global\let\csq@oqmark\csq@oqmark@nogroup
    \global\let\csq@qclose@ii\csq@qclose@ii@orig
    #1%
  \else
    \csq@addkern@close
    \ifodd\csq@qlevel
      \csq@thequote@oclose
      \let\csq@kernchar@i\csq@thequote@oclose
    \else
      \csq@thequote@iclose
      \let\csq@kernchar@i\csq@thequote@iclose
    \fi
    \ifnum\csq@qlevel>\@ne
      \csq@setmarker@close
    \fi
    \global\advance\csq@qlevel\m@ne
    \global\let\csq@oqmark\csq@oqmark@nogroup
    \global\let\csq@qclose@ii\csq@qclose@ii@orig
    \ifblank{#1}{}{\expandafter#1}%
      \expandafter\def
      \expandafter\csq@kernchar@i
      \expandafter{\csq@kernchar@i}%
    \expandafter\csq@fixkern
  \fi}

\makeatother

\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
    \enquote{Bold text 1}

    "{\bfseries Bold text2}"

    \enquote{Bold text 1}

    "{\bfseries Wrong" text3}
\end{document}
```

[image: „Bold text 1“//„Bold text2“//„Bold text 1“//„Wrong“ text3]

If you ask me, I'd try to stick to using quotes only at the same grouping levels. If that is absolutely not possible for some reason, I'd use the manual `\textooquote` and `\textcoquote` in that case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
    \enquote{Bold text 1}

    "{\bfseries Bold text2}"

    \enquote{Bold text 1}

    \textooquote {\bfseries Wrong\textcoquote\ text3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I stick for the very moment with the idea of doing the stuff manually, ie. `\textooquote` and `\textcoquote` - especially if you say your other solution might be fragile. The main reason why I cannot control the grouping is due to the fact of automatic transformation from HTML to TeX. What is valid in HTML might lead to complications in TeX, e.g. the above sample of quotes.I'm happy to have this kind of idea now.

Comment: @LeO I see. Just curious: Does that sort of thing (quotes at different grouping levels) happen often in your texts? At least the `\bfseries` example looks really weird. And even for most other things I would have expected the group to either start before the quotation and span all of it or to be confined to inside the quotation.

Comment: Well - honestly I don't know if it happens 'often' or not. Matter of fact is that the compile process shouldn't be terminated due a error which only a TeX expert could trace down to the root cause. So, if there would be some settings which would handle the whole situation in a graceful way - than this would be perfect. Otherwise I'll stick to the manual approach.